# An array of enum members using implicit member syntax

Tags: arrays, swift, syntax, enums

Consider this `enum`.

```
enum FilmGenre: String, CaseIterable {
    case horror = "Horror"
    case comedy = "Comedy"
    case animation = "Animation"
    case romance = "Romance"
    case fantasy = "Fantasy"
    case adventure = "Adventure"
}
```

Is there a way to write it like this?

```
let filmGenres: [FilmGenre.RawValue] = [.horror.rawValue,
                                        .comedy.rawValue,
                                        .animation.rawValue]
```

The compiler complains with an error:

> Type 'FilmGenre.RawValue' (aka 'String') has no member 'horror'

The best I can do is like this.

```
let filmGenres: [FilmGenre.RawValue] = [FilmGenre.horror.rawValue,
                                        FilmGenre.comedy.rawValue,
                                        FilmGenre.animation.rawValue]
```

I've tried various combinations from the auto-complete.

```
let filmGenres: [FilmGenre.AllCases.Element.RawValue] = [...]
```

Is it not possible to do it in `Swift` 5.4?

Comment: The idea is to restrict the array to the `enum` members raw value. No other string values are allowed. I could add a random string which is completely unrelated to the `enum` members raw value. If I changed the array to `[String]` annotation, it can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

`[FilmGenre.RawValue]` translates to `[String]` in the case and clearly `String` doesn't know anything about `.horror` that is defined in other type `FilmGenre`.

What you can do is -

```
enum FilmGenre: String, CaseIterable {
    case horror = "Horror"
    case comedy = "Comedy"
    case animation = "Animation"
    case romance = "Romance"
    case fantasy = "Fantasy"
    case adventure = "Adventure"
}

/// Have a variable that is of `[FilmGenre]` type
/// This will allow you to use the type safety you are looking for
let filmGenres: [FilmGenre] = [.horror, .comedy, .animation]

/// This one you can use anywhere else as you like
/// This will give you `[String]` which is what you want in this case
let filmGenreRawValues = filmGenres.map({ $0.rawValue })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a static function with var args to your enum for a more dynamic way to create the array

```
static func arrayWithRawValues(_ genre: FilmGenre...) -> [Self.RawValue] {
    genre.map(\.rawValue)
 }
```

Example

```
print(FilmGenre.arrayWithRawValues(.horror, .comedy, .animation))
```

Output

> ["Horror", "Comedy", "Animation"]